# How to 'Multiple update rows once a row is deleted"? Using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm sorry for this might be a silly question, but I would like some help to get the logic in forming the correct syntax on my problem.
Language used: PHP, MySQL

Here's the scenario:

I have a table named tbl_book

```
+----+------+-------+------------+
| id | code |  copy | date_added |
+----+------+-------+------------+
| 1  | IX3V |   1   | 2018-12-09 |
| 2  | IX3V |   2   | 2018-12-09 |
| 4  | BN9Z |   1   | 2018-12-10 |
| 5  | BN9Z |   2   | 2018-12-10 |
| 6  | BN9Z |   3   | 2018-12-11 |
| 7  | BN9Z |   4   | 2018-12-12 |
| 8  | BN9Z |   5   | 2018-12-12 |
+----+------+-------+------------+
```

Now, for instance I would like to delete id=6. After deleting that row,
I would like to set all copy set from 1,2,4,5 to 1,2,3,4 where code = BN9Z.

Expected Output:

```
+----+------+-------+------------+
| id | code |  copy | date_added |
+----+------+-------+------------+
| 1  | IX3V |   1   | 2018-12-09 |
| 2  | IX3V |   2   | 2018-12-09 |
| 4  | BN9Z |   1   | 2018-12-10 |
| 5  | BN9Z |   2   | 2018-12-10 |
| 7  | BN9Z |   3   | 2018-12-12 |
| 8  | BN9Z |   4   | 2018-12-12 |
+----+------+-------+------------+
```

This problem is for my project and I would be glad to tick for a relevant solution. Thank you.

Comment: While you could do that, it would involve updating several rows. You might consider just deleting the row with the max value of *copy*.

Comment: I can't delete, I forgot to put the 'date_added' column. If to be deleted, it would be like adding new copy. PS. I'll update the table.

Comment: When I red the word "once", database **triggers** came to my head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the values of `code` and `copy` of the row you are deleting, you could use this:

```
UPDATE `tbl_book`
SET `copy` = `copy`-1
WHERE `code` = `BN9Z` and `copy` > 3
```

---

**UPDATE**

Here's some code that will remove the rows and update later (by id) rows.

mysql_... functions are depreciated, and have been removed from the current (7) version of PHP. Use mysqli functions instead.

```
include("db_connect.php");  //  Update to use mysqli functions instead of mysql functions.

$get_to_delete_no = "3";
//  Get the info from the row to be deleted
$rowinfo = mysqli_query("SELECT `id`,`code`,`copy` FROM `tbl_book` WHERE `id` = $get_to_delete_no");
if($rowinfo !== false) {
    $rslt = mysqli_query("DELETE FROM `tbl_book` WHERE `id` = $get_to_delete_no");
    if($rslt !== false) {
        $rslt = mysqli_query("UPDATE `tbl_book` SET `copy` = `copy` - 1 WHERE `copy` > ".$rowinfo[0][`copy`]." AND `code` = ".$rowinfo[0][`code`]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sloan this seams to be a good suggestion @Markus You should do both qeuries in a transaction if InnoDB as table engine is used because of possible race conditions..

Comment: @RaymondNijland sir. I'm still quite confused on how to do it. Can you help me sir?

Comment: @SloanThrasher - it seems to be that I can't manage to construct it. Can you help me? Here is what I did: include("db_connect.php"); $get_to_delete_no = "3"; mysql_query("DELETE FROM tbl_book WHERE id = '6' "); $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_book "); while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ $get_copy = $row["copy"]; mysql_query("UPDATE tbl_book SET copy = '$get_copy'-1 WHERE code = 'BN9Z' AND copy > '$get_to_delete_no' "); } It seems to be that the rest turned to 0 on copy column. Can you reconstruct mine? Thank you. Sorry for trouble.